# save data from a table when a select or checkbox is selected in angular js

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

im trying to save the data from a table when a checkbox or selectbox is selected.
Table when loaded

---

code Product Checkbox  SelectBox

---

0    45        checkbox   selectoption

---

11  78         check box   selectoption

---

html code:

```
<tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in Codes.CodesDetails">

                   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="code.Presentstatus" id="Checkbox" name="Checkbox" /></td>
        <td><select id="reasons" name="reasons" ng-model="code.Category" ng-disabled="code.Presentstatus" ng-clicked="code.Presentstatus && O" ></td>

    </tr>       <input  type="button" value="save" ng-click="module.RegisterDetails"/>
```

the checkbox is checked it must show me a value of one and ignore the selectbox and vice versa.
but this is the output I get
Code= 0,Product=45,CheckBox="",selectbox=""

sorry about the table structure

Comment: You should add a js fiddle to make your question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the ng-click you just add the following`

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="code.Presentstatus" id="PresentCheckbox" name="PresentCheckbox" ng-click="code.Category=0"/></td>
    <td><select id="reasons" name="reasons" ng-model="code.Category" ng-disabled="code.Presentstatus" ng-click="code.PresentStatus=false"  ></td>
```

`